# How to get to send the current network's server using nodejs

Tags: node.js, server, ip, client, ethernet

I'm currently creating a client application with nodejs. But everytime i test it outside the server computer then I have to use its internel IP address to send request to server. I want something that can do this without using its server's IP. Is it possible? I'm using ethernet and switch in this case.
Thank you.

Comment: When using TCP, clients contact servers by connecting to the server's IP address.  That's how it works.  You either get the IP address manually somehow or you use DNS to lookup the IP address using a publicly known and available hostname (such as "google.com") and DNS then tells you what the IP address is.  For local networks only, there are a few other "resource discovery" protocols.  But, on the big, bad internet, you must use either a direct, public IP address or use a DNS name to lookup the public IP address.

Comment: jfriend00 thanks but exactly what is "resource discovery" ? how to do that with nodejs

Comment: There are various resource discovery protocols in different operating systems.  Apple has Bonjour to find things like printers on the local LAN.  Some others are listed here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-configuration_networking#Service_discovery.  If your server is "on the internet", then you will want to use DNS as these resource/service discovery services are for finding resources on the local LAN, not on the internet.